# How to find/update nested documents in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nested-lists

it is possibly a Mongo database architecture question. With my current architecture I hit a hurdle how to properly update my documents. Here is what I did:

The task is to model a very large XML/HTML document in Mongo. This document can be edited by multiple users simultaneously, where each person would edit their own part of the document. Every sentence in the document has an ID and can be referenced to from other parts of the document. The sentences can move around the document but references will be preserved thanks to unique IDs. These requirements result in the document being modelled in Mongo as a set of nested arrays of documents. The challenge is to retrieve and update any sentence or document within the structure quickly.

Here is the question: how to retrieve nested documents by their IDs quickly when I don't know the structure beforehand? Further, It'll also be necessary to update fields in these nested documents. Is it possible to run a Mongo query that would do this, or do I need to traverse the tree manually and also build custom functionality to handle concurrent document updates? Just to get an idea, I have a structure like the one below but with more fields and unlimited amount of levels. I want to run a query like this:

```
MyCollection.find({ _id : ObjectID("myID") } )
```

Obviously this doesn't retrieve nested documents by their IDs.

The structure is:

```
{      
  "id_": {
    "$oid": "5488732a44ae21d08f94fb6f"
  },
  "container": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "5488742344ae21d08f94fb70"
      },
      "container": [
        [
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "5488746c44ae21d08f94fb71" },
              "container" : [
                  etc.
                ]                
          },
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "5488748444ae21d08f94fb72"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "548874a744ae21d08f94fb73"
      },
      "container": [
        {
          "etc": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

PS. I'm new to Mongo, so I haven't done anything that might look obvious to an experienced MongoDB developer, like setting indexes.

Comment: At the least, you don't want to use a MongoDB document to model arbitrarily nested structures. I'd suggest reading over the options detailed in the MongoDB Manual on [modeling tree structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). Arrays-of-ancestors and materialized paths sound most promising to me but you should evaluate them in the context of all of your requirements.